# A recursive definition

Tags: induction, recursive-algorithms

I have this problem: Q4 of [this](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~radko/circles/lib/data/Handout-334-416.pdf)

1. Prove by induction that no matter how the dots are coloured red and
   blue, it is possible to have a successful trip around the circle if you start
   at the correct point.

But I have another point that I don't know how to do

2.Use the above proof to give a recursive denition for the "correct
point".

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you did it already, but let me try to answer what they are asking. Let CorrectPoint($x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2n}$) denote the point that causes a win for $2n$ dots.

First, CorrectPoint($x_1,x_2$) is equal to whichever of $x_1$ and $x_2$ is the red dot.

Second, for $n\geq 2$ and given $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2n})$, first identify a pair $(x_i,x_{i+1})$, such that $x_i$ is red, and $x_{i+1}$ is blue, and then define

CorrectPoint($x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2n}$) = CorrectPoint($x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+2},\ldots,x_{2n}$).

I hope this was what you were aiming for.